# Retrieving project from azure after driver crash

Tags: c#, azure, compilation

So my visual studio crashed and I restarted the computer and my whole E: is now gone. But I am working on a project now that I had uploaded to azure and I want to download that from azure. So i found this program called [JustCompile](https://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) that can uncompile dll files. But the problem is that it doesn't return fully to the original code. Take this as a example (was 80% less code originally)

```
Expression<Func<User, object>>[] expressionArray = new Expression<Func<User, object>>[2];
            ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User), "user");
            expressionArray[0] = Expression.Lambda<Func<User, object>>(Expression.Property(parameterExpression, (MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(typeof(Principal).GetMethod("get_Title").MethodHandle)), new ParameterExpression[] { parameterExpression });
            parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User), "user");
            expressionArray[1] = Expression.Lambda<Func<User, object>>(Expression.Property(parameterExpression, (MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(typeof(Principal).GetMethod("get_LoginName").MethodHandle)), new ParameterExpression[] { parameterExpression });
```

And I cant go through all files and change them manually its to much work. Is it possible to retrieve a project from azure and have that code be exactly the same as when I published it?

Answer (score 1):

If the compiled version of the project is all you have left, I think you should be happy with *any* code you can recover... There's several decompilers available, like [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy). The results will probably be similar.

For future reference, please look into [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) like [VSTS](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/) or [GitHub](https://github.com/).

Comment: Yeah I usually use TFS but this time I dint... future note to self always use cloud based storage